# What is pythonic way to do memory save column aggregations?

Tags: python, performance, list, memory, aggregate

I'm new to python and sorry if this is a stupid question. I have table like data structure and want to apply different aggrefation function to each column to get some kind of `total` row:

```
data = [
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
   [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
]
agg_func = [sum, min, max, mean, median]

total_row = [agg_func[index](value) for index, value in enumerate(zip(*data))]
```

If this is proper way (in terms of ram saving) to do that kind of aggregation if i have a lots of data (millions of rows in data)? Is here is any way to do such kind of computations faster?

Comment: Yes, it the good way to do it memory-wise assuming you already have all the millions of rows of data in memory at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `numpy` for this kind of computation. It allows you to apply an aggregation function on the first dimension of a high-dimensional structure.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
])
agg_func = [np.sum, np.min, np.max, np.mean, np.median]
total_row = [f(data, axis=0) for f in agg_func]
```